# Idiom or proverb for 'wherever there are industrious people, wealth is produced'

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

Wherever there are industrious people, wealth is produced. 
**where bees are, there is honey** Does this count as a proverb for the above phrase? If not, what are the equivalent English proverbs or idioms for the same?

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to respond with  "There's a sucker born every minute," since that sentence is most often sent from the rich and powerful to the poor and overworked.

Comment: I think British English, anyway, dropped that concept a long, long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the *[Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GtBxCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=where%20there%20is%20honey%20there%20are%20bees&source=bl&ots=2AfT81Pdfw&sig=ahS2Y7KhW5ZDQT3hahKMxDYe0bo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwg9m23JPWAhVPalAKHay2A5sQ6AEISjAI#v=onepage&q=where%20there%20is%20honey%20there%20are%20bees&f=false)*, so you're probably OK!

It comes from the Latin: *ubi mel, ibi apes*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A relevant entry in the [Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780198734901.001.0001/acref-9780198734901-e-1506?rskey=bsf5AQ&result=1)* is

> **Where there’s muck there’s brass**
>
> In the original agricultural context of this saying, farming, which involves muck (manure) and mud, was a route to wealth. Brass is a slang and dialectal word for ‘money’ here.
>
> 1678 J. Ray *English Proverbs* (ed. 2) 179 Muck and money go together.
> 1855 H. G. Bohn *Hand‐Book of Proverbs* 564 Where there is muck there is money.
> 1943 J. W. Day *Farming Adventure* xii. ‘Where there’s muck there’s money’ is as true now as then. But farms today lack the mud.
> 1967 *Punch* 13 Sept. 396 ‘Where there’s muck there’s brass’ synopsised for many a North‐country businessman the value of dirt in the profit‐making process.
> 2001 *Spectator* 15/22 Dec. 28 Where there’s muck, there’s brass, and it was the job of the stercorarius to empty the cesspits and sell on the contents to farmers on city outskirts.

Although the original context was agricultural, use has broadened to any hard work — not necessarily manual labour, although some element of grime is usually required.

<sub>*Sign-in is probably required. A public library subscription may be sufficient.</sub>